# ¿Cómo hacer la comparativa entre diferentes array de números aleatorios y un array de enteros?

Tags: c

Necesito hacer un programa que compare una lista de números aleatorios y otra lista de gente creada por el usuario
Tengo algo de código, pero no logro hacer que me cuente las coincidencias, he intentado con la biblioteca string.h y usando puras cosas de stdio.h pero o logro hacer que se comparen los arreglos y saber sus coincidencias

Comment: Hola @Danniixxx si pudieras subir el código completo desde las líneas de las librerías que incluiste se nos hiciera más fácil de resolver tu problema, ya que así solo compilamos y vemos la parte del código que no funciona bien

Comment: Si pudieras especificar un poco mejor que es lo que no puedes comparar. ¿Son datos de tipo entero con datos tipo string los que no puedes comparar?

Comment: Intento comparar 2 grupos de números enteros , uno de números aleatorios y otro de números metidos por el usuario, la cantidad de números la decide el usuario

Comment: `n` no tiene un valor inicial, así que cuando haces `N[n]` le estas dando un tamaño indefinido al array (Bien puede ser `0`, o ser `-7987`, que te dará resultados curiosos). Si no te quieres complicar con `malloc` y `free`, solo has el array suficientemente grande (Quien va a querer mas de 100?), y usa solo parte del espacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo la solución del código. Con un for anidado puedes realizar las comparaciones que necesitas. Escribí algunas sugerencias y explicaciones como comentarios en el código. Si la respuesta te fue de ayuda márcala con el check como la correcta.

**Con respecto al tamaño del arreglo** la solución es declarar la variable que le da el tamaño al arreglo igual a 0 inicialmente `int n=0;`, para que luego `n` tome el valor que el usuario ingrese. Así evitas que el arreglo sea **innecesariamente grande o que tome valores indefinidos debido a una mala declaración.**

Para poder hacer la comparación de los números ganadores con los números que el usuario eligió debes guardar los **números ganadores en un arreglo** para así poder compararlos con los números que el usuario eligió, esta comparaci[on se logra mediante for anidados.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n=0, num=0;
    int contador, Respuesta;
        //Si inicializas aquí el arreglo el tamaño es indefinido y te puede causar errore mayores,
        //por lo que recomiendo crear el arreglo luego de saber su tamaño N[n];
    char nombre[50];
    srand(time(NULL));
    do {
        printf("¿Crees que la suerte esta de tu lado?\nBienenido al sorteo Fi UNAM\n\n");
        printf("Ingresa tu nombre\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",&nombre);
        printf("¿Cuantos valores deseas introducir?\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        //Aquí se inicializa el arreglo principal, donde el usuario insertará los datos
        int N[n];
        //Debes crear otro arreglo, con el que puedas comparar los datos ingresados por el usuario
        int NC[n];
        printf("Recuerda, los valores deben de estar entre 0 y 250\n");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            do {
                scanf("%d",&num);
                /* Esta parte debe ir dentro del if, ya que si el usuario ingresa un número fuera de rango entonces no lo guarde en el arreglo
                N[i]=num;
                printf("- - - - -\n");
                */
                if(num<0 || num>250){
                    printf("Numero no valido, ingrese de nuevo el valor\n");
                }else{
                    N[i]=num;
                    printf("- - - - -\n");
                }

            } while (num<0 || num>250);
        }
        system("cls");
        printf("Tu nombre de usuario es: %s\n",nombre);
        printf("Tus numeros seleccionados fueron:\n");

//        cout<<n<<endl;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            num=N[i];
            printf("%d\n",num);
        }
        printf("Los numeros premiados fueron:\n");
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            //Los números aleatorios deberían ser entre 0 y 250
            NC[i]=rand()%10;
            fflush(stdin);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            cout<<NC[i]<<endl;
        }

        //Este es el algoritmo que necesitas para comparar los datos
        int coincidencias = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                if(N[i] == NC[j]){
                    coincidencias++;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("Se registraron %d coincidencias \n", coincidencias);
        printf("¿Desea iniciar una nueva partida? (Si=0, No=1)\n");
        scanf("%i", &Respuesta);
        system("cls");
    } while (Respuesta != 1);
    printf("FIN DEL JUEGO");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió bastante